# Display Created Date of Document using Content Query webpart

Tags: document, content-query-web-part, web, date, whencreated

I'm using a Web Part to display a list of filtered pdfs on a page.
Managed to get the document name to list without a hitch, but can't find a way to add the date the pdf was added to Sharepoint.

For info, to insert the Web Part in the page I hit Insert on the ribbon, then Web Part, then selected Content Rollup and Content Query.

On looking through the Web Part options, I can see under Presentation there is a field called Title. Currently this contains only Title; - is this the place that will add in a new column with the date created information? If so, what do I need to enter?

Any help on my novice user question would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try to create a custom item style that will show the Title and date as the following

[image]

Steps:

- via SharePoint Designer > Open your Root site.
- Go to all files > `Style library` > `XSL Style Sheets` > `ItemStyle.xml`
- Create a copy from `ItemStyle.xml` to allow rollback then > Edit it as advanced mode.

[image]

Add new style with name `TitleDate` as the following

```
<xsl:template name="TitleDate" match="Row[@Style='Actions']" mode="itemstyle">
    <xsl:variable name="SafeLinkUrl">
        <xsl:call-template name="OuterTemplate.GetSafeLink">
            <xsl:with-param name="UrlColumnName" select="'LinkUrl'"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="DisplayTitle">
        <xsl:call-template name="OuterTemplate.GetTitle">
            <xsl:with-param name="Title" select="@Title"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="UrlColumnName" select="'LinkUrl'"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>
    <div class="item link-item">
        <xsl:call-template name="OuterTemplate.CallPresenceStatusIconTemplate"/>
        <a href="{$SafeLinkUrl}" title="{@LinkToolTip}">
          <xsl:if test="$ItemsHaveStreams = 'True'">
            <xsl:attribute name="onclick">
              <xsl:value-of select="@OnClickForWebRendering"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
          </xsl:if>
          <xsl:if test="$ItemsHaveStreams != 'True' and @OpenInNewWindow = 'True'">
            <xsl:attribute name="onclick">
              <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="$OnClickTargetAttribute"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
          </xsl:if>
          <xsl:value-of select="$DisplayTitle"/>
        </a>
        <div style="color:black">
          <xsl:value-of select="ddwrt:FormatDate(string(@Actiondeliverydate), 2057, 3)" />
        </div>
    </div>
</xsl:template>
```

- Save > Check In > Publish as Major Version.
- After you finish > go to your QCWP > Edit it > and select your custom style from Presentation > Styles > Item Style > select your new item style `TitleDate`.
- In title field, Provide Title.
- In date field, provide the internal name of your date field name.

**Note:**

In the above example: I used `@Actiondeliverydate` but when you edit your CQWP web part, you should provide the internal name  of `'Action delivery date'` field that in this case is `Action_x0020_delivery_x0020_date` that will be transferred back to `Action delivery date`

Comment: Hi Mohammed, I can't see date field according to your instructions above.Can you please verify?

Answer (score 0):

Open the `itemstyle.xsl` file in style library.

There you need to add the following line at the top:

```
xmlns:ddwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime
```

So overall it will look as below:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" exclude-result-prefixes="x d xsl msxsl cmswrt" 
  xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/dsp" 
  xmlns:cmswrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v3/Publishing/runtime"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
  xmlns:ddwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime">
```

After that, in your xsl template , you need to simply add the below line:

```
<xsl:value-of select="ddwrt:FormatDate(@Created, 2057, 3)"/>
```

Reference - [Custom Date Formats in SharePoint XSL](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/joshuag/2009/03/25/custom-date-formats-in-sharepoint-xsl/)

[Customize itemstyle.xsl](https://panvega.wordpress.com/2008/06/03/customize-itemstylexsl-for-contentquery-webpart/)